# Tomcat version 5.5 authentication log

Tags: tomcat

I need some help to log authentication requests (users ids and other request details) in tomcat 5.5. I am publishing web services in this tomcat server.
Can some one help me with the steps to do that please ?

Comment: Please describe what have you done so far.

Comment: I have set log.enabled to true in tomcat.properties. Post that I can see the requests in the tomcat.log file.  Entry 1 : 127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2016:04:32:04 -0400] "GET /server/vdb_datahub_rita/i_hub_stg_loan_agrmt/ HTTP/1.1" 403 1119

Entry 2 :127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2016:04:33:29 -0400] "GET /server/vdb_datahub_rita/i_hub_stg_loan_agrmt/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2029.  Entry 1 has status 403 that means fail and entry 2 has a status of 200 that means success. However the user that made the request is not logged. I want that information as well.